# How do I get all the commands related to the JVM?

Tags: java, jvm

When monitoring the JVM, I often use jps, jmap, etc. Then I want to know how to get or where to have documentation to know all the commands about the JVM?

Comment: go to `bin` directory of your standard JDK installation and list all executable.

Comment: Or look at the documentation on the Oracle website; e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.ヾ(≧O≦)〃